# Detect multiple group elements contain same class by using hasClass

Tags: jquery

I have one question which confused me for a couple of days. It's about how to use `.hasClass()` to detect all ul groups have at least one  with class active in order to proceed the form (combine with jQuery validation)

```
<form id="rate"> 
<ul class="scoreList listRe listR2">
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="scoreList listRe listR2">
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="scoreList listRe listR3">
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
</ul>

</from>
```

I was writing jQuery as follows and I think it has problems (although it is working)

```
$('#rate').validate({
              submitHandler: function(form) {
                if($('.listR1 a').hasClass('active')&&$('.listR2 a').hasClass('active')&&$('.listR3 a').hasClass('active'))
                {
                    form.submit();
                }
                else{
                    alert("You must rate all!!!");
                    return false;
                };
             }
            });
```

But I am thinking about if I can do sth as follows:

```
if($('.listR1 a' && '.listR2 a' && 'listR3 a').hasClass())
                {
                    form.submit();
                }
                else{
                    alert("You must rate all!!!");
                    return false;
                };
```

Do you guys have any ideas on this? I will be very appreciated.

Best Regards,
Jessie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var ul = $("[class*=listR]")
, active = function (elem) {
    var arr = $.grep(elem, function (el, i) {
        return $(el).find("a").is(".active")
    });
    return arr.length !== elem.length ? false : true
};

$('#rate').validate({
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        if (active(ul)) {
            form.submit();
        } else {
            alert("You must rate all!!!");
            return false;
        };
    }
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/qbLgh8yj/

```js
var ul = $("[class*=listR]")
, button = $("button")
, label = $("label")
, active = function (elem) {
    var arr = $.grep(elem, function (el, i) {
        return $(el).find("a").is(".active")
    });
    return arr.length !== elem.length ? false : true
};
label.text(active(ul));
button.one("click", function() {
  ul.find("a.active").toggleClass("active");
  label.text(active(ul));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>toggle active</button><label for="button"></label>
<ul class="scoreList listRe listR2">
    <li><a href="#">5</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">1</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="scoreList listRe listR2">
    <li><a href="#">5</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">1</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="scoreList listRe listR3">
    <li><a href="#">5</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">1</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the class name in the selector, then check it's length. Ex:

```
if ( $('.div1.active').length > 0 && $('.div2.active').length > 0 ) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Is that like I need to list all my class to test the length?

Comment: If the length is greater than zero, it exists. And since the selector includes the class, it will return 0 if the class is not in fact applied. Try it - it works well and is very little code.